# Recursively adding to binary tree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to recursively add to a binary tree in Haskell. I'm following [*Learn You A Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com) on this, only with a few changes, but I'm getting errors, which I do not understand:

```hs
data Male = Male { maleName :: String
                 , maleDOB :: Int
                 } deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

data Female = Female { femaleName :: String
                     , femaleDOB :: Int
                     } deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

data FamilyTree a = EmptyTree 
                  | Node a (FamilyTree Female) (FamilyTree Male)
                  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

singleton :: a -> FamilyTree a
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> FamilyTree a -> FamilyTree a
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x
treeInsert x (Node a left right)
    | x == a = Node x left right
    | x < a  = Node a (treeInsert x left) right
    | x > a  = Node a left (treeInsert x right)
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Couldn't match type `Female' with `Male'
Expected type: Male
  Actual type: a
In the first argument of `treeInsert', namely `x'
In the third argument of `Node', namely `(treeInsert x right)'
In the expression: Node a left (treeInsert x right)
```

I'm quite new to Haskell and can't wrap my head around what is happening here. Any pointer in the right direction would be welcome!

Comment: you mix this up to much - see in `FamilyTree` the subtrees `a` are constrainted to be `Male` for left and `Female` for right - so you cannot insert your general `x` there anymore!

Comment: I think I know what you are trying here but in this case you should do `data Person = Male ... | Female ...` and then construct your tree of type `FamilyTree Person` so that the left nodes (the first component of those) are only Male, ... also it's a bit strange to use the *sorted*  behavior ... as surely your mother should have a father and mother too ... so it's gonna be hard to write an `Ord` instance for said persons

Comment: Thanks, got alot further no and am on track hopefully. Tanks!

Comment: Not exactly related to your question, but it's better style to do `case compare x a of { LT -> ... ; EQ -> ... ; GT -> ... }`, since this only requires performing one comparison, rather than three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
treeInsert :: Ord a => a -> FamilyTree a -> FamilyTree a
```

the type system ensures that the type of the first argument equals the index of the second. It means that you can insert a `Male` only in a tree that starts from a `Male`. I guess, this is not what you want.

However it's a nice question and I'll answer it. The problem in

```
treeInsert :: Ord a => a -> FamilyTree a -> FamilyTree a
```

is that `a` is far to general. What would

```
treeInsert :: Int -> FamilyTree Int -> FamilyTree Int
```

mean? You need to restrict `a` to be either `Female` or `Male`. That's a job for `GADTs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Person a where
    PFemale :: Female -> Person Female
    PMale   :: Male   -> Person Male
```

`Person` contains either `Female` or `Male` and carries at the type level information about which one. Having this we can define

```
runPerson :: Person a -> a
runPerson (PFemale x) = x
runPerson (PMale   x) = x

treeInsert :: Person a -> FamilyTree a -> FamilyTree a
treeInsert p              EmptyTree          = singleton (runPerson p)
treeInsert p@(PFemale x) (Node a left right)
    | x == a    = Node x left right
    | otherwise = treeInsert p left
treeInsert p@(PMale   x) (Node a left right)
    | x == a    = Node x left right
    | otherwise = treeInsert p right
```

The trick is that when you pattern match on `Person a` `a` gets instantiated either to `Female` or `Male` and never to something else. When `a` is `Female`, you continue to insert into the "`Female`" subtree, otherwise — into the "`Male`".